# how to sum specific columns in data.frame R?

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have a data frame like `LowData` below. I have not the vectors `country`, `House` or `Seats`, only the result data frame.

```
country <- rep(c("Greece","Cuba","Rwanda"),2)
House <- rep(c("LowerHouse","Senate"),each = 3)
Seats <-  c(300,605,80,0,0,26)
LowData <- data.frame(COUNTRY=country,HOUSE=House,SEATS=Seats)
```

How can I add the seats of each country and make automatically a vector like `AllSeats` below?

```
AllSeats <- c(300,605,106)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `aggregate(SEATS~COUNTRY, LowData, sum)` Or with `tapply(LowData$SEATS, LowData$COUNTRY, sum)`

Comment: @RonakShah , thanks a lot. I wrote `aggregate(LowData$SEATS, by=list(Category=LowData$COUNTRY), FUN=sum)`. Is it the same?

Comment: Yes, that is true. It's the same.